# Control over New Items on Site Home Page

Tags: site

I have a simple Site with a list and some views. I do not want the end users to be able to see the "New" Items on the home page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can create a view for the list and restrict user (add filter) to view only items created by current user.

Comment: That is not what I am asking. On the Home Page there is a new with "List, Library, App" etc. This is what I do not want the users to see.

Comment: For that you can break inheritance for the list and remove all groups access from the list. Add only the specific groups who needs to create items. Exclude the groups where end user are members of.

Answer (score 0):

You can change webpart's toolbar type to "No Toolbar":

[image]

This should remove "New" button. The only problem is that it will also remove other buttons like and "Sync".

Comment: Denis, thank you for posting, sorry for the tardy reply.  The problem I have is that the home page is not a web part, it is a page. I could not find the way to take away the toolbar or the individual new items. What I ended up doing is making a new Page and setting it to the home page. Not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get any of these responses to work, although I do really appreciate the input. What I finally did was to make a new page and put some text on it and then made that the home page. Now the users will not see the New button on this page.

Answer (score 0):

Bryan. I assume when you say you want to hide any "new" items, that you're talking about anything with the "new" indicator that shows up next to it? If so, the default time period the "new" label shows is for two days after an item is created.

Provided you haven't changed that value (see below link for the value that would need changed), you would want to simulate the same filter in your view by updating the webpart's view to filter out anything created in the last 2 days, and thus, you would be removing "new" items from your page.

You'd do that by Setting [Created] "is less than" [Today]-2

[image]

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.daystoshownewindicator.aspx

Comment: Looking at other comments, it looks like maybe you didn't mean "new" items, and you meant "new" buttons. If users shouldn't have the ability to add new items, then the permissions should reflect that, and the button will not show. Otherwise, if you're just hiding the toolbar on a particular view on a page, you'd want to follow the other answer below where you set the Toolbar Type to no toolbar. If you wanted to hide  only 'New' buttons, you could use css to do this. I'd have to see the specific structure of the page, and the version of SharePoint, to understand the rule you'd want to write.